# How to plot cycloid curve?

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry, cycloid

I have having trouble plotting the curve. It only plots half of the curve, what may be missing here?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid#Equations

> x = r arccos (1 - y/r) - sqrt (2ry - y^2)

Plot https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/nvujgvgw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the form of equation you have entered into geogebra is treated by geogebra as a function. Therefore, for the sqrt() function it only returns the positive value.

To get geogebra to plot the full curve you will have to enter the parametric equation given in Wikipedia using the geogebra curve() command.
For example, with $r$ set to 5,
$$Curve(5 (t-sin(t)),5 (1-cos(t)),t,0,4 π)  $$
This should do two cycles.